# Remapping of Database from one server to other TFS-2018

Tags: .net, visual-studio, tfs

we have single tier architecture and we are planning to move to 3 tier architecture, the problem is how i can remap my database to different database server. it dosent looks as simple as changing the connection string.

Comment: Hey PatricLu, you are awesome, your reply was really helpful in fact completely dependable. few learning and your steps helped completely. thanks alot for the help. I am replying late because the implementation was complete in last week. thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a little complicated process.

You need  to  perform multiple steps such as:

- Back up data
- Stop services
- Restore the databases
- Prepare SQL Server
- Change the ownership of the restored databases
- Update all service accounts
- Clear the data cache on servers
- Restart services
- Refresh the data cache on client computers

More details please take a look at our official tutorial here: [Restore data to a different server than the current one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/backup/restore-data-different-instance?view=azure-devops)